# How to add a value into an object which is inside map function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using map function to iterate an object. but in one scenario i have to use nested map function. I try to add an value to an empty object inside an map function, but instead of adding values it replacing it. can anyone help me with this?

```js
// object stores final results
let valid_data={}
//object to iterate
let test_cases = { 
sample:
   [ { test_case_no: 1,
       test_case_description: 'user-status active - response 200',
       value: 'active',
       response_code: 200,
       valid: 'yes' },
     { test_case_no: 2,
       test_case_description: 'user-status inactive - response 200',
       value: 'inactive',
       response_code: 200,
       valid: 'no' },
     { test_case_no: 3,
       test_case_description: ' inappropriate user-status - response 400',
       value: 'notAdmin',
       response_code: 400,
       valid: 'no' } ],
     sample1: [ { obj1: [Array], obj2: [Array], test_case_no: 4 } ] 
}

//my code to iterate an object

Object.entries(test_cases).map((property) => {
    const field_name = property[0]
    const field_definition = property[1]

    Object.entries(field_definition).map((property) => {
        if (property[1].valid != 'yes' && property[1].valid != 'no') {
            Object.entries(field_definition).map((property) => {
                Object.entries(property[1]).map((propertyy) => {
                    Object.entries(propertyy[1]).map((property) => {
                        nested_data = []
                        nested_value = {}
                        if (property[1].valid == 'yes') {
                            nested_value[propertyy[0]] = property[1].value
                            nested_data.push(Object.assign({}, nested_value))
                            valid_data[field_name] = (Object.assign({}, nested_value))
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        }
        else if (property[1].valid == 'yes') {
            valid_data[field_name] = property[1].value;
        }
    })
})

console.log(valid_data);
```

**Actual result:**

```
“{ sample: 'active',
 sample1: { obj2: 2019-07-01T09:50:46.266Z } }”
```

**Expected result:**

```
“{ sample: 'active',
 sample1: [{ obj1: 2019-07-01T09:50:46.266Z,obj2: 2019-07-01T09:50:46.266Z }] }”
```

Comment: what's `valid_data()`?

Comment: that's an empty object declared outside the map functions. The expected results will be stored in it @GrafiCodeStudio

Comment: Can you explain in short what you wana do?

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj I snippetted your code and the actual result seems to be`{ "sample": "active" }`

Comment: Most of the time, you only access an object's values, use `Object.values` in those cases, also, you're not actually mapping arrays, you only seem to iterate them, use `.forEach` instead of `.map`.

Comment: i need to iterate an test_cases variable to get an output like expected output. but i am failing to get that@SaimaHaji

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio that's a value for sample key,  I am making use of values to assign them to respective keys.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong var initialisation in your code.
Try this loop :

```
Object.entries(test_cases).map((property) => {
    const field_name = property[0]
    const field_definition = property[1]

    Object.entries(field_definition).map((property) => {
        if (property[1].valid != 'yes' && property[1].valid != 'no') {
            nested_value = {}
            Object.entries(property[1]).map((propertyy) => {

                Object.entries(propertyy[1]).map((property) => {

                    if (property[1].valid == 'yes') {
                        nested_value[propertyy[0]] = property[1].value;
                        valid_data[field_name] = (Object.assign({}, 
                        nested_value))
                    }
               })
            })
        } else if (property[1].valid == 'yes') {
            valid_data[field_name] = property[1].value;
        }
    })
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u93a2mrb/)

Comment: Thanks for your input, Almost done but, only difference is the two values should be  inside single object. but in this case it creates two objects.
output for your code
 { sample: 'active',
  sample1:
   [ { obj1: 2019-07-01T11:09:45.426Z },
     { obj2: 2019-07-01T11:09:45.426Z } ] }

Comment: still array is missing. you can check my answer i had posted it yesterday. and thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.entries(test_cases).map((property) => {
    const field_name = property[0]
    const field_definition = property[1]

    Object.entries(field_definition).map((property) => {
        if (property[1].valid != 'yes' && property[1].valid != 'no') {
            nested_data = []
            nested_value = {}
            Object.entries(property[1]).map((propertyy) => {                
                Object.entries(propertyy[1]).map((property) => {
                    if (property[1].valid == 'yes') {
                        nested_value[propertyy[0]] = property[1].value;                       
                        if(!nested_data.includes(nested_value)){
                            nested_data.push(nested_value)
                        valid_data[field_name] = nested_data
                        }
                    }
               })
            })
        } else if (property[1].valid == 'yes') {
            valid_data[field_name] = property[1].value;
        }
    })
})
```